# Android webview and dynamically loaded histats.js file

Tags: android, webview, google-analytics

-- Problem solved. The cauase was a malicious DNS server that masks google analytics code and loads altered code --

For 8 hours I'm struggling with a javascript file, still I couldn't solve issue.

In my Android application I use webview. So normally it loades pages from my webserver. But it seems like, when my android application is installed firstly, After page load a dynamical js file is loaded.

When I debug I see in my WebView's `onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)` method, it is from histats.com. I don't use histats page. I only use statcounter and google analytics.

So it seems like, one of the content of my page dynamically loads [histats.js](http://s10.histats.com/js15_as.js). When histats is loaded it shows an Adsense advertisement on top of my page. You can find loaded js files below.

To test this case, everytime I uninstall my application and reinstall it. Because this behaviour only happens in the first webview load.

Temporarily I stopped loading Google analytics code to not to show the advirtesements, that are loaded by histats. When analytics.js is not loaded, histats.js doesn't load or doesn't show an advertisement. But I need a permanent solution. Also note that when `onLoadResource` is fired, histats.js file is already loaded.

Notes:
- I don't think that will be the cause but last week I activated [demographics and interests report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357)
- In my website I use adsense but my opening page doesn't have adsense code.

So how can I find out which element causes this ?

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.4.33/example1/colorbox.css

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/colorbox/1.5.6/jquery.colorbox-min.js
http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
http://c.statcounter.com/t.php?sc_project=9470079&resolution=480&h=800&camefrom=&u=http%3A//example.com/mains/mypage/&t=Mobile%20hub%20-%20example.com&java=1&security=f927fd2c&sc_random=0.5743160555139184&sc_snum=1&p=0&invisible=1
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

http://s10.histats.com/js15_as.js
http://ad.exisolutions.com/gads/sp_336x280.html
http://s4.histats.com/stats/0.php?2672616&@f16&@g1&@h1&@i1&@j1400933555245&@k0&@l1&@mMobile%20hub%20-%20example.com&@n0&@o1000&@q0&@r0&@s0&@ten-IE&@u480&@vhttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmains%2Fmypage%2F&@w
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js
http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/html/r20140520/r20140417/zrt_lookup.html
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20140520/r20140417/show_ads_impl.js
http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-4244446356287789&format=336x280&output=html&h=280&slotname=1396969791&adk=1267119624&w=336&ea=0&flash=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmains%2Fmypage%2F&dt=1400933556220&bpp=179&shv=r20140520&cbv=r20140417&saldr=aa&correlator=1400933557079&frm=24&ga_vid=931282578.1400933557&ga_sid=1400933557&ga_hid=1996810608&ga_fc=0&u_tz=180&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=800&u_w=480&u_ah=800&u_aw=480&u_cd=32&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&dff=sans-serif&dfs=16&adx=0&ady=0&biw=-12245933&bih=-12245933&isw=336&ish=280&ifk=1348755138&eid=317150304%2C317150313&oid=3&rx=0&eae=2&jp=2&brdim=0%2C38%2C0%2C38%2C480%2C0%2C480%2C762%2C336%2C280&vis=1&fu=0&ifi=1&dtd=967
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js
http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/formats/templates.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/images/adc-i-00aecd.png
http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/simgad/17675984934948895957
http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/images/mobile_unified_button_icon_white.png
http://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=3&s=gmob&action=&rt=crf.526,cri.947
http://www.gstatic.com/bg/BcR1_JHsmtBAKR1Crki_wuwBn2NQgHTsJL0mibVeye0.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activeview?id=osdim&avi=BAqEktoyAU9C0FaTHiQa57YGoCwCJuoeQugEAABABOAHIAQKgBgKoE4AB&adk=1267119624&p=0,0,280,336&tos=0,0,0,0,0&mtos=0,0,0,0,0&rs=1&ht=0&swf=-&fp=client%3Dca-pub-4244446356287789%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fmains%252Fmypage%252F%26correlator%3D1400933557079%26ifk%3D1348755138%26eid%3D317150304%252C317150313%26oid%3D3&afp=%26format%3D336x280%26output%3Dhtml%26slotname%3D1396969791%26flash%3D0%26dt%3D1400933556220%26adx%3D0%26ady%3D0%26ifi%3D1&r=i&bs=-12245933,-12245933&bos=480,762&ps=-12245933,-12245933&ss=480,800&tt=2470&pt=2195&deb=1-1-1-4-5--1&iframe_loc=http%3A%2F%2Fad.exisolutions.com%2Fgads%2Fsp_336x280.html&is=336,280
http://s4.histats.com/stats/e.php?2672616&@Ab&@R78479&@w
```

I also added following script to end of my page. And checked for HTML code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var htmlData=$("html").html();
            var formData = {html:htmlData};
            $.ajax({
                url : "/log_this/",
                type: "POST",
                data : formData
            });
        }, 4000);
    });
</script>
```

It seems like this code is injected to the head section of webpage:

```
  < script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://s10.histats.com/js15_as.js" >
 < /script >
 < script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://s10.histats.com/js15_as.js" >
  < /script >
```

**Edit 1:**
histats also loads this page: http://ad.exisolutions.com/gads/sp_336x280.html
Regarding to that page's source, it loads adsense ads with this publisher: `ca-pub-4244446356287789`

**Edit 2:**
I beautified initial file to find out who injects this.
Ugly file: http://s10.histats.com/js15_as.js
You can find beautified version here: http://jsbin.com/tenunike/1/

**Edit 3:**
To isolate the problem I stopped all css and js file includes.
No adsense occured. But then I enabled google analytics js file include it happened again.
So histats.js file is included whenever I include [google analytics.js](http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js) file

**Edit 4:**
After getting that problem is based on google analytis code, I checked my development environment for viruses, etc. So I get that a virus changed my DNS server to an unknown IP, like this: 37.220.8.189.
So analytics code address is this: http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
But my DNS server gives this IP: 188.165.174.188
So resultant analaytics file is this, it has malicious code in it: `http://188.165.174.188/analytics.js`
I put a copy of this malicious code here for future references: http://jsbin.com/mukijojo/1/edit

**Edit 5:**
For months this problem occurs every once in a while. So I add mlicious DNS serer address here:
37.220.8.189
31.3.252.69 and 31.3.252.68

Also similar problems:
https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/10/01/hacked-routers-brazil-vb2012/
http://www.cbits.co.uk/ourblog/news/fake-flash-player-update-virus-routers-tp-link/
http://www.gohacking.com/dns-hijacking/
http://www.gohacking.com/hack-ethernet-adsl-router/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
The cauase was a malicious DNS server that masks google analytics code and loads altered code.
When I try to access

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
```

actually I was reaching

```
http://188.165.174.188/analytics.js
```

Although the IP address of  `188.165.174.188` doesn't belong to Google IP ranges.

info:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSChanger
checking: http://www.dcwg.org/detect/
fixing: http://www.dcwg.org/fix/